# The consistency of $\Sigma_1$-elementary embeddings $j\colon V_{\lambda+2}\to V_{\lambda+2}$ over $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

One way to stratify the large cardinal hierarchy between I3 and I1 is by using second-order elementary embeddings. We may view $j\colon V_{\lambda+1}\to V_{\lambda+1}$ as a second-order embedding $j\colon (V_\lambda,V_{\lambda+1})\to (V_\lambda,V_{\lambda+1})$, and it is known that $\mathrm{I2}(\lambda)$ is equivalent to there is an $\Sigma^1_1$-elementary embedding $j\colon (V_\lambda,V_{\lambda+1})\to (V_\lambda,V_{\lambda+1})$, or equivalently, $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding over $V_{\lambda+1}$ to itself.
(A sentence is $\Sigma^1_1$ if it is of the form $\exists X\subseteq V_\lambda \phi^{V_\lambda}(x)$.)

Laver proved that $\Sigma^1_{2n-1}$-elementary embedding is also $\Sigma^1_{2n}$-elementary for $n\ge 1$, and if there is a $\Sigma^1_{2n+1}$-elementary embedding $j\colon V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$, then we can find $\lambda'<\lambda$ and a $\Sigma^1_{2n-1}$-elementary $k\colon V_{\lambda'}\to V_{\lambda'}$.

We may turn our view to third-order embeddings $j\colon V_{\lambda+2}\to V_{\lambda+2}$, or alternatively, $\Sigma_n$-elementary embeddings over $V_{\lambda+2}$. Of course, full elementary embedding $j\colon V_{\lambda+2}\to V_{\lambda+2}$ is incompatible with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but it does not automatically rule out all $\Sigma_n$-elementary embeddings over $V_{\lambda+2}$ to itself. On the other hand, coding Woodin's proof into $V_{\lambda+2}$ seems to exclude $\Sigma_n$-elementary embeddings over $V_{\lambda+2}$ for some $n$ (maybe $n\ge 2$?)

> **Question.** Is a $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding $j\colon V_{\lambda+2}\to  V_{\lambda+2}$ compatible with $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not consistent. If $j : V_{\lambda+2}\to V_{\lambda+2}$ is $\Sigma_1$-elementary, then $\mathcal U = \{A\subseteq P(V_\lambda) : j[V_\lambda]\in j(A)\}$ is a normal fine ultrafilter concentrating on $\sigma$ such that $\text{ot}(\sigma\cap \lambda) = \lambda.$ Then taking an ultrapower of the universe, we obtain an elementary embedding $j_\mathcal U : V \to M$ with $j_{\mathcal U}[V_\lambda] = [\text{id}]_{\mathcal U}\in M$ and $j_{\mathcal U}(\lambda) = \lambda$, contrary to Kunen's inconsistency theorem.

For more information (and in the ZF context), see section 4.3 (Reinhardt ultrafilters) of my joint paper ["Periodicity in the cumulative hierarchy"](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/26941) with Farmer Schlutzenberg. The work in this section is for the most part due to Farmer.

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, I found that a stronger result may hold:

> **Claim.** ($\mathsf{ZF}$) Let $j\colon V_{\lambda+2}\to V_{\lambda+2}$ be a $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding such that $j(V_{\lambda+1})=V_{\lambda+1}$.
>
> Furthermore, assume that the following collection principle holds for $V_{\lambda+2}$: For every $a\in V_{\lambda+2}$ and $R\subseteq a\times V_{\lambda+2}$, if $\forall x\in a\exists y R(x,y)$ then we can find $b,c\in V_{\lambda+2}$ such that $\forall x\in a\exists z\in c R(x,(b)_z)$. (See the later part for the definition of $(b)_z$.)
>
> Then $j$ is fully elementary.

Its proof starts by showing the following lemma, whose proof can be done by simple computation:

> **Lemma.** The following statements are all $\Delta_0$ over $V_{\lambda+2}$ with some parameters:
>
> 1. $z=\lceil x,y\rceil$, where $\lceil \cdot,\cdot\rceil$ is a Quine-Rosser pairing function.
> 2. $z=\pi_0(p)$ and $z=\pi_1(p)$, where $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ are projection function for Quine-Rosser pairing function.
> 3. $z=(x)_y$, where $(x)_y=\{w\mid \lceil y,w\rceil \in x\}$.

Its proof starts from inspecting the definition of the pairing function: Remind that if we define $s(x)=x\cup\{x\mid x\in\omega\}$, $f_0(X)=s^"[X]$, $f_1(X)=s^"[X]\cup\{0\}$, then $\lceil x,y\rceil = (f^"_0[x])\cup (f^"_1[y])$. We can see

$$y=s(x) \iff \forall z\in x (z\in y)\land (x\in\omega\to x\in y)\land \forall z\in y [z\in x\lor (x\in\omega\land z=x)]$$
and
$$y=f_0(x) \iff \forall z\in y\exists w\in x (z=s(w)) \land \forall w\in x\exists z\in y(z=s(w)).$$
We can similarly express $y=f_1(x)$, and with similar tedious writings, we can see all notions mentioned in the lemma are $\Delta_0$.

Now examine the proof of Lemma 3.9 of [Periodicity in the cumulative hierarchy](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01103) by Goldberg and Schlutzenberg. Since $j(V_{\lambda+1})= V_{\lambda+1}$, $j\upharpoonright V_{\lambda+1}$ is a fully elementary embedding from $V_{\lambda+1}$ to itself, $(j\upharpoonright V_\lambda)^+= j\upharpoonright V_{\lambda+1}$. We can also see that the remaining part of the proof of Lemma 3.9 carries over from the given assumption. Hence $j$ is cofinal, that is, it satisfies

> For every $a\in V_{\lambda+2}$, we can find $b,c\in V_{\lambda+2}$ such that $a\in (j(b)\mid j(c))$, where $(b\mid c)=\{(b)_x\mid x\in c\}$.

Now I claim that $j$ is $\Sigma_1$-elementary. Suppose that we have
$V_{\lambda+2}\models\exists x \phi(x,j(t))$, where $\phi$ is $\Delta_0$. That is, we have $a\in V_{\lambda+2}$ such that $\phi(a,j(t))$ holds. By cofinality, we can find $b,c\in V_{\lambda+2}$ such that $a\in (j(b)\mid j(c))$. That is, we have some $x\in j(c)$ such that $a=(j(b))_x$, so
$$V_{\lambda+2}\models \exists x\in j(c) \phi{\large(} (j(b))_x, j(t){\large)}.$$
We want to see that the formula $\phi{\large(} (j(b))_x, j(t){\large)}$ is equivalent to a $\Delta_0$-formula. It is not entirely obvious because the easiest formulation for the previous formula is
$$\exists z (z= (j(b))_x)\land \phi(z,j(t)),$$
which is $\Delta_1$.

To get a $\Delta_0$-expression for $\phi{\large(} (j(b))_x, j(t){\large)}$, we claim that the following formulas are all equivalent to some $\Delta_0$-formula, where $\psi$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula:

1. $z=(a)_x$,
2. $(a)_x\in z$,
3. $z\in (a)_x$,
4. $\exists z\in (a)_x \psi(z,t)$,
5. $\forall z\in (a)_x \psi(z,t)$.

Then we replace all such formulas to the corresponding $\Delta_0$-formula to get a $\Delta_0$-expression for $\phi{\large(} (j(b))_x, j(t){\large)}$.

But showing that the above formulas are equivalent to a $\Delta_0$-formula is not hard: For example, $z=(a)_x$ is equivalent to
$$\forall w\in z\exists p\in a (p=\lceil x,w\rceil) \land \forall p\in a\exists w\in z (p=\lceil x,w\rceil),$$
and for the quantifier case, we can see $\exists z\in (a)_x \psi(z,t)$ is equivalent to $\exists p\in a (\pi_0(p)=x\land \psi(\pi_1(p),t))$, and $\psi(\pi_1(p),t))$ is equivalent to a $\Delta_0$-formula:

> **Lemma.** Let $\psi(x,y)$ be a $\Delta_0$-formula. Then $\psi(\pi_1(x),y)$ is equivalent to a $\Delta_0$-formula with parameter $V_{\lambda+1}$.
>
> *Proof.* It suffices to show that formulas of the form $\exists z\in \pi_1(x)\psi(z,t)$ and $\forall z\in \pi_1(x)\psi(z,t)$ are equivalent to a $\Delta_0$-formula. Observe that $z\in \pi_1(x)$ is equivalent to $f_1(z)\in x$, and $x\subseteq V_{\lambda+1}$. Hence $\exists z\in \pi_1(x)\psi(z,t)$ is equivalent to
> $$\exists z\in V_{\lambda+1} [f_1(z)\in x\land \psi(z,t)].$$
> The remaining case is similar.

Going back to the proof for the main claim, we can see that the remaining cases are easy or analogous.

Hence $\exists x\in j(c) \phi{\large(} (j(b))_x, j(t){\large)}$ is equivalent to a $\Delta_0$-formula, and so by $\Delta_0$-elementarity of $j$, we get $V_{\lambda+2}\models \exists x\in c\phi ((b)_x,t)$, so $V_{\lambda+2}\models \exists x \phi(x,t)$.
We can repeat a similar manipulation to get the full elementarity of $j$, so $j$ is fully elementary.

Comment: What do you mean by you can "repeat a similar manipulation to get full elementarity"? Let $\varphi$ be $\Sigma_0$ and $p\in V_{\lambda+2}$. Suppose for all $x\in V_{\lambda+1}$ there is $y\in V_{\lambda+2}$ such that $\varphi(x,y,p)$. Why does it follow that for all $x\in V_{\lambda+1}$, there is $y\in V_{\lambda+2}$ such that $\varphi(x,y,j(p))$?

Comment: @FarmerS Oh, I see what you pointed out, and I do not see why it should work. Le me add an assumption on $\lambda$ to make my proof to work for higher $n$, but it makes my result weaker (although it still answers my original question.)